# Dynamically changing flashvars using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, flash, flashvars, flash-video

I have creating a fallback flash player for my HTML5 video player, to work on internet explorer 8. I require the ability for the user to select which video he would like to play out of a wide range, so I have tried using jQuery to change the embed flashvars value - which works fine using this code:

```
$('#f').attr('flashvars', 'newvideofile.mp4');
```

Nothing happens visually when I have ran this piece of code, however if I look at my code through inspector I can see that the flashvars value has updated to the new value.

Is there something I can do to 'reload' or 'update' the embed object as such - or is there any other alternative that someone can think of to dynamically change the embed video in the frame?

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Jamie

Comment: You could use `ExternalInterface` (Actionscript) but you need to change the SWF for that. Otherwise you can re-embed the SWF with those flashvars. How do you embed it now? With JavaScript or manually?

Comment: The first video has been embedded manually

Comment: What about the `ExternalInterface`? Is it your own flashplayer? Do you know how to do change it?

Comment: It is not my own flashplayer, but the files are included. I don't know how to change it but I'm assuming if I figured that out then it would be possible to run my project as I imagine, changing the flash files dynamically?

Comment: It depends on the way that the flashplayer works. But it is possible to use JavaScript together with `ExternalInterface.callback()` to dynamically change the flashvars yes.

Comment: If you're not familiar with Actionscript or you just cannot edit the Flash code (to make it aware of and respond to changes in FlashVars), then the first idea by @putvande is probably your only recourse: remove and re-embed the SWF when you change the FlashVars. You could use the SWFObject library to remove/embed the SWF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update flashvars and reload flash with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861517/update-flashvars-and-reload-flash-with-jquery)